# How can I setup Eclipse to develop Griffon applications?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, griffon

Is there any plugin that I can install in Eclipse so as to develop Griffon applications?

Basically, how can I do Griffon application development with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Griffon plugin for Eclipse yet, however you can use the Ant integration to get by. The Guide explains how you can set it up http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#ideSetup

*UPDATE*: As of Griffon 2.x there's a different way to setup Eclipse/Maven, see http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html

Comment: I'm using Maven for my project. Can I integrate with Maven so as to run ( I mean `griffon start-app` )  and other commands from within Eclipse?

Comment: Maven support is still in incubation, you can build your own copy from https://github.com/nbn/griffon-maven-plugin

Comment: The Griffon Maven plugin is available, but it does not replace the griffon shell yet. It just partake in the build cycle. However, you can compile, test and package your app through Maven

Comment: Link is dead as of 2018-02-13

Comment: This answer applies to Griffon 1.x; for Griffon 2.x have a look at http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html